# Texture does not fit the screen

Tags: android, textures, matrix, opengl-es, ndk

Hi guys I am really new in OpenGL-ES and I am developing a simple android application with NDK, and I just want to ask why the image is not fit after I set the width and height of it.

this is my `width` and `height`

```
const int FIXED_WIDTH = 320;
const int FIXED_HEIGHT = 568;
```

and this is how I set my `Matrix`

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

// Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the same
// while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
float left = FIXED_WIDTH;
float right = 0.0f;
float bottom = FIXED_HEIGHT;
float top = 0.0f;
float near = 1.0f;
float far = 50.0f;

mProjectionMatrix = Matrix::newFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

// Position the eye in front of the origin.
float eyeX = 0.0f;
float eyeY = 0.0f;
float eyeZ = 1.0f;

// We are looking at the origin
float centerX = 0.0f;
float centerY = 0.0f;
float centerZ = 0.0f;

// Set our up vector.
float upX = 0.0f;
float upY = 1.0f;
float upZ = 0.0f;

// Set the view matrix.
mViewMatrix = Matrix::newLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);

// model * view * projection
mMVPMatrix->multiply(*mProjectionMatrix, *mViewMatrix);
```

After setting the `Matrix` I thought that my point 0.0 will start at the **top right** corner of the device (This is my understanding of **matrix**). as you shown in the image.

[image]

and this is how I setup my `texture`

```
TextureGenerator* textureGenerator = new TextureGenerator();
textureGenerator->setSize(320.0f, 568.0f); // width and height
textureGenerator->setTranslate(0.0f, 0.0f); // X and Y
textureGenerator->setTextureId(GLUtils::loadTexture("bg.jpg"));
mTextureCollection.push_back(textureGenerator);
```

then after I add some `texture` this is the result.

[image]

This is the actual picture, size 320x568.

[image]

as you can see to the result of my doing, I don't know if my point 0.0 is starting at the center. Please someone help and explain to me why the texture is not fit, and if my `matrix` is correctly set or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very right about your guess that the "point 0.0 is starting at the center" - simply looking at the screenshot you can see it is the bottom left corner of your texture.
The provided code example only confirms the suspicion:

```
// We are looking at the origin
float centerX = 0.0f;
float centerY = 0.0f;
float centerZ = 0.0f;
```

which is setting the view *center* to `[0,0,0]`. Adjusting either the quad position or the eye+center position by `[-w/2, h/2]` should do the trick. Suggested further reading:
[Understanding glm::lookAt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830340/understanding-glmlookat?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
[Getting started with OpenGL coordinate system](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems)
[Viewing and Transformations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations)

Comment: thanks for answering, but what do you mean by this `[-w/2, h/2]`? Is this how I declare my textures? because this is how I declare my texture. 

`mTextureSize[0] = -(width  / 2.0f); // Left`
`mTextureSize[1] =   height / 2.0f;  // Top`
`mTextureSize[2] =   width  / 2.0f;  // Right`
`mTextureSize[3] = -(height / 2.0f); // Bottom`

Is this also the reason why my images display to the upper right of the screen instead of fitting it to the screen?

Comment: @Jer the texture is cropped by screen because most of it lies outside rendered area. You need to move either the texture quad (model matrix) or the camera (view matrix). The former could be trivially done by `textureGenerator->setTranslate(-w/2, -h/2);` latter is done by offsetting `eye`'s and `center`'s corresponding coordinates (e.g. `centerX += -(w / 2.0f)`). You can learn that and much more from the linked resources.

Comment: Ohh.. you are right... Thank you, now my texture is rendering on the 0.0 point now. what I've done is 

    `mTextureSize[0] = mWidth; // Left`
    `mTextureSize[1] = mHeight;  // Top`
    `mTextureSize[2] = 0.0f;  // Right`
    `mTextureSize[3] = 0.0f; // Bottom`

Instead of setting a negative number of texture I set some part of it to 0.0 and the other part is the entered width and height of it.

Comment: though I see your comment more useful rather than your answer, I still mark it as an accepted because you put some useful links, Thanks again.